# Powershell Ambiguous Code Running on Windows Machine

Tags: powershell

Out of sudden, a colleague of mine found a script that runs during the startup of the Windows on his machine, which is found to be a powershell script.

The code is below, what I understood that it only minimizes all windows opened.

```
powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"
```

I need to know if there is an impact from this code on his machine as to isolate from the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to present a threat in and of itself. If someone is doing something unwanted, it would probably be that they're starting some other program that does something not nice, and this PowerShell command minimizes its window (possibly to the taskbar notification area where it can be hidden) so that you don't see what's going on. But the command itself appears harmless.

Comment: So, it is preferable to fully scan the device?

Comment: Always a good idea to fully scan for viruses and the like once in a while!

Answer (score 1):

It only minimizes all the windows. Except that nothing else. I don't think it is harmful. If someone has kept it in the startup, I believe the reason being some other App is opening window in the startup , so it is trying to avoid that.